# Sum previous row values in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to sum value in pervious rows, I want to sum the pervious quantity "Stock on hand" and put the result in each row, example

| ItemID | Qty | Stockon Hand ( the result updated in this column) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | 1 |
| 1000 | 5 | 6 ( sum qty previous in pervious row plus the qty in the current row) |
| 1000 | 2 | 8 ( sum qty previous in pervious row plus the qty in the current row) |
| 1000 | 1 | 9 ( sum qty previous in pervious row plus the qty in the current row) |

How can I update the column "Stock on hand" by summing the qty in the current row and previous rows?

```
select ItemID, Qty
    , sum(qty) over (order by itemid rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as previous_Qty
from #Stock
order by itemid
```

Comment: I'm using 2012 but my customer using 2008

Comment: Is there another column which would have a proper sequence like datetime or identity?

Comment: Yes, ID is identity and the Datetime also exist, order by ItemID, Datetime

Comment: I removed tag 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example.  Note, I took the liberty of adding an column for a proper sequence... ID, but you could use a date column as well

You may also notice that I added `partition by ItemID`

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[ItemID] int,[Qty] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,1000,1)
,(2,1000,5)
,(3,1000,2)
,(4,1000,1)
 
Select * 
      ,OnHand = sum(Qty) over (partition by ItemID order by ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
from @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
ID  ItemID  Qty OnHand
1   1000    1   1
2   1000    5   6
3   1000    2   8
4   1000    1   9
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. It's working 100%

Comment: @DaleK - That is, frankly, condescending. This is a question and answer site. People don't know what they don't know. Or have been working on the problem for so long that they need a second set of eyes. To turn it around for you, doing nothing in this case would have been faster than tossing out discouragement.

Comment: @DaleK Very true.   The best lessons are the hardest lessons.  That said, sometimes people need a little nudge and see it in action with their data.